# core.wait command -- am I using pyglet or not?

Tags: psychopy

I've set up an experiment in the Builder to obtain rapid reaction times to audio stimuli, and I've subsequently been playing with the code to get the experiment to do exactly what I want. In particular, I'd like very accurate reaction times, so the program would ideally hog the CPU from the onset of each stimulus until a fixed point afterwards, and record keypresses of "w" and "e" during this time.

In an attempt to achieve this, I've been resetting the clock at the start of the audio stimuli, then hogging the CPU for for 2secs, as follows:

```
event.clearEvents(eventType='keyboard')
response.clock.reset()
core.wait(2,2)
if response.status == STARTED:
theseKeys = event.getKeys(keyList=['w', 'e'])
```

This seems to work fine. However, I have one concern: the documentation for the `core.wait` command says:

> If you want to obtain key-presses during the wait, be sure to use pyglet.

How would I know if I'm using pyglet? Is it automatic, or do I need to alter the script in some way to ensure that I'm using it?

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the type of window (pyglet or pygame) that you are using to display your stimuli. PsychoPy will generally use pyglet, but to be sure, you can explicitly set the window type when you create it. See the window API at http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/window.html:

> winType : None, ‘pyglet’, ‘pygame’
>
> If None then PsychoPy will revert
>   to user/site preferences

More importantly, make sure you are using the pyo audio library rather than the default pygame. Set this in the PsychoPy Preferences -> General -> Audio Library dialog box field. Pygame definitely has sound latency problems: you should assume that there is a substantial lag between telling a sound to play and sound actually being produced. Pyo does better apparently, but I think you should validate this independently in some way to ensure that your reaction times to auditory stimuli are meaningful.